# how to read virtual serial port of MIB520

Tags: java, serial-port, virtual-serial-port, tinyos, nesc

i need to read from my Pc the serial port that connected with [MIB520](http://www.willow.co.uk/html/mib520-_usb_gateway.html) usb board ?

if i know the sequence of the data received byte by byte then can i use C# or any tool to read this port ??

i have iris and MicAz motes that read gps packet then they send them to the mote which attached to the [MIB520](http://www.willow.co.uk/html/mib520-_usb_gateway.html) usb board.

note: that MIB 520 use two virtual ports,it use `FTDI FT2232C`

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general question about connecting to serial ports via USB, so I'll point you to some sources of general information.

First of all, your machine will need to have the FTDI [drivers](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) installed.

If you want to manually interact with the serial device by typing commands and reading responses, you can use a terminal emulator like `minicom` or `gtkterm`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347962/how-to-connect-to-a-terminal-to-serial-usb-device-on-ubuntu-10-10) has some related information in the answers.

If you are looking for a java serial library, there are several you could try:

- [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

  - [serterm](https://code.google.com/p/serterm/): An example project built with RXTX
- javax.comm
- [jSSC](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/)