# Minicom is not starting

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, stm32, hardware-interface

I am trying to run NuttX on STM32f429I. I have build nuttX and flashed the nuttx to the device. But after flashing when i am trying to start minicom, it showing this problem

```
minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
```

I already followed all the steps given in this [How to connect to a terminal to Serial-USB device on Ubuntu 10.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347962/how-to-connect-to-a-terminal-to-serial-usb-device-on-ubuntu-10-10)  post.

I am getting this after Serial Post setup from minicom.

[image]

Checking with `lsusb`

[image]

Checking with `dmesg | grep tty`

[image]

I have also checked with *ttyUSB1,ttyUSB2, ttyACM1,ttyACM0* etc.

result of `sudo lsusb -v`
[image]

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39lntX-8tfk) tutorial. My machine is Ubuntu 16.04LTE

Edit:

[image]

```
~/nuttxworkspace/nuttx$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.888895] 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[25292.460385] cdc_acm 2-1.5:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason that you would expect to see /dev/ttyUSB0?  Do you have CDC/ACM device class configured?  What does your configuration use for a serial console?  I would expect it would use the STLink-VCOM port.  There won't be any USB connection unless you have full configured it that way.

Comment: How can i check that ?

Comment: Look what is set up for the console in your .config file

Comment: how can i configure CDC/ACM ? or STLink-VCOM ?

Comment: by using stlinkv2_2 i am able to start minicom, but after clicking reset button i am not able to start nsh